# How to restrict user to query on information_schema?

Tags: postgresql

How is possible to restrict user from querying this query:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema."tables"
```

As for the moment I onyl gave him Can Login:

[image]

And no memberships:
[image]

But login as this user this query still returns results.

Comment: On top of the answer below, one thing to note is that the information schema generally only shows what the user is allowed to see / interact with. E.g. the `tables` view only shows the tables the user has access to: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-tables.html

Comment: The views in `information_schema` only show tables (or other objects) that the current user has access to. So why would you want to restrict that further? If the user is allowed to run `select * from some_table` then why shouldn't they be allowed to run `select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'some_table'`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So the solution should be just to revoke the user access to the object and that should include the `information_scheme` also.

Comment: In addition see my comment to the answer on why this is a futile exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This disallow everything on the information_schema.tables:

```
revoke all privileges on table information_schema."tables" from "<username>";
```

You can fine tune the restriction for instance only the read access:

```
revoke select on table information_schema."tables" from "<username>";
```

Comment: That only works until the user finds out they can query the same information from the Postgres system catalogs e.g. pg_class, pg_proc, pg_database, etc. And those tables can't be restricted. So the above is not really going to do anything, especially as a user is restricted to what they see in the information_schema to what they have rights to on the original objects anyway.